# Regex: Find the property used on the first parameter of the function

Tags: javascript, regex

In my code, I need regex to find the dynamic key of the first parameter in all of these function string cases:

```
x => x.id // should return 'id'

x => x.a.biggerThan(5) // should return 'a'

x=>x.b.biggerThan(5) // should return 'b'

test => test.c.biggerThan(5) // should return 'c'

(x, y) => x.d.biggerThan(5) // should return 'd'

x => { return x.e.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'e'

(x, y) => { y = test.description; return x.f.biggerThan(y); } // should return 'f'

function (x) { return x.g.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'g'

function test(x) { return x.h.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'h'

function(x) { return x.i.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'i'

function(x){ return x.j.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'j'

function (x, y) { return x.l.biggerThan(5); } // should return 'l'
```

-- Expanation of why I need it --

These are functions stringfied with `toString()` method and I need to create a dynamic object that has that key to insert in that function, like this:

```
// get the key used by the function
const key = getkeyInFunc(func.toString());

// construct a dynamic object using that key
const builder = {
  [key]: {
    biggerThan: // biggerThan function
    // others methods
  }
};

// call the function with the dynamic key as parameter
const result = func(builder);
```

Please help me because I'm terrible with regex =(

Comment: But the `id` key is always `id`?

Comment: Sorry... it's not. It's any possible js property key

Comment: This to me seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'd highly recommend you explain what you're _actually_ trying to do, or provide some context about the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I edited with more information. Please check if it's clear now

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue, considering your example cases: if you have a string `function test(x) { return x.h.biggerThan(5); }`, how do you expect it to match `a`?

Comment: Sorry... I misplaced the key in comment... I edited

Comment: Why not x => x.['a'].biggerThan(5) ? Just with a variable instead of 'a'

Comment: Yes, I know it could be easier... but unfortunately it is my client request, so I'm trying to find a way to do it (and I know it can be done with regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this examples it will work

"functionString".match(/(return |=> )[a-zA-Z_0-9]+?.([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/)[2]

example:

`"(x, y) => { y = test.description; return x.f.biggerTha_n(y); }".match(/(return |=> )[a-zA-Z_0-9]+?\.([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/)[2]`

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I only needed to insert a `\` before `.` and a `?` after the space of the `=>` to match the 3rd case that is a arrow function without space. Thank you a lot!

Comment: `\ `  before `.`

Comment: This is how all cases matched: `/(return *|=> *?)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+?\.([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

var result = /return \w+.([a-z]+)./.exec((function (x) { return x.id.something(); }).toString());

result[1]; // id

where the slash starts the regular expression an tries to match the part of the string where there is a 'return' keyword follow by a character (\w) and then a dot and with the '()' groups the key you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will work when the function is in es5 format with `return` keyword but won't match with es6 arrow function. I need to match all those type because it will be used for each es6 and es5 javascript codes.